# Format [TIMESTAMP] field value in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, database, ibm-midrange

I am composing a [SEQUEL ViewPoint](http://www.sequel-software.com/products/sequel) query joining 2 tables. The first table has the following fields: `Action`, `SSAN`, `MEMNO`, `RSCODE`, `USERID`, and `TIMESTAMP` which is in the format of (Ex. `2005-03-11-09.54.18.296000`). The other tables is simply used to get the Member `NAME` by joining the two tables on `SSAN`.

Why my query starts, the user is presented with a dialog for a date which I have designated as `StartDate`. The idea is to return all desired fields where `table1.TIMESTAMP` value is greater than the user selected `StartDate`.

My current query looks like so:

```
 SELECT         memno.1 EDTCDE(L), name.2, 'SYS1' NAME(SYS), "&&startdate" NAME(StartDate), CURRENT DATE NAME(CurDate)
 FROM           library1/table1, library1/table2
 JOIN               SSAN.1=SSAN.2
 WHERE          TIMESTAMP>StartDate AND RSCODE='STP'
 UNION 
 SELECT         memno.1 EDTCDE(L), name.2, 'SYS2' NAME(SYS), "&&startdate" NAME(StartDate), CURRENT DATE NAME(CurDate)
 FROM           library2/table1, library2/table1
 JOIN               SSAN.1=SSAN.2
 WHERE          TIMESTAMP>StartDate AND RSCODE='STP'
 ORDER BY   sys ASC, memno ASC
```

Which results in:

```
Fields TIMESTAMP and STARTDATE in WHERE clause are not compatible.
Cause. . . . .: You are trying to compare two fields that not compatible. One of the following is true:
1 -- One field is numeric and the other is not numeric (character or date/time)
2 -- One field is character and the other is not character (numeric or date/time)
3 -- One field is double-byte and the other is single byte.
```

This is clearly due to my `table1.TIMESTAMP` filed being in (Ex. `2005-03-11-09.54.18.296000`) format and my query value `StartDate` being in (ex. `01/01/14)`.

How can I format my `TIMESTAMP` value in the `WHERE` clause in order to compare it with my `StartDate` value? (Or is there a better way to go about this? I'm still pretty green when it comes to SQL and Database QWerying)

### **EDIT:**

Using ***Roopesh***' suggestion of  `timestamp > cast(StartDate as datetime)` results in:

```
 SELECT         memno.1 EDTCDE(L), name.2, 'SYS1' NAME(SYS), "&&startdate" NAME(StartDate), CURRENT DATE NAME(CurDate)
 FROM           library1/table1, library1/table2
 JOIN               SSAN.1=SSAN.2
 WHERE          TIMESTAMP>Cast(StartDate as datetime) AND RSCODE='STP'
 UNION 
 SELECT         memno.1 EDTCDE(L), name.2, 'SYS2' NAME(SYS), "&&startdate" NAME(StartDate), CURRENT DATE NAME(CurDate)
 FROM           library2/table1, library2/table1
 JOIN               SSAN.1=SSAN.2
 WHERE          TIMESTAMP>Cast(StartDate as datetime) AND RSCODE='STP'
 ORDER BY   sys ASC, memno ASC
```

`There is an error in the WHERE clause. Parser expected ")". Continue Anyway?` [YES selected]

I select date `01/01/14` which shows in the sql as `"01/01/14 NAME(StartDate)` and receive:

```
 Identifier 'AS' preceding ' datetime)' is used incorrectly.
    Proper SQL syntax rules have been viloated. The identifier cannot occur where it has been found in the statement. Instad of 'AS', SQL syntax rules allow only: ) ,. If you are using *SEQUEL object authority checking, you cannot use runtime variables in place of the allowed values.
```

---

Using ***Notulysses***' suggestion:

Variable `StartDate` is of Type `Date` with a length of `10`, defaulted to `01/01/2014`.

```
 SELECT         memno.1 EDTCDE(L), name.2, 'SYS1' NAME(SYS), "&&startdate" NAME(StartDate), CURRENT DATE NAME(CurDate)
 FROM           library1/table1, library1/table2
 JOIN               SSAN.1=SSAN.2
 WHERE          CAST(TIMESTAMP as Date)>StartDate AND RSCODE='STP
 UNION 
 SELECT         memno.1 EDTCDE(L), name.2, 'SYS2' NAME(SYS), "&&startdate" NAME(StartDate), CURRENT DATE NAME(CurDate)
 FROM           library2/table1, library2/table1
 JOIN               SSAN.1=SSAN.2
 WHERE          CAST(TIMESTAMP as Date)>StartDate AND RSCODE='STP
 ORDER BY   sys ASC, memno ASC
```

`There is an error in the WHERE clause. Parser expected ")". Continue Anyway?` [YES selected]

I select date `01/01/14` which shows in the sql as `"01/01/14 NAME(StartDate)` and receive:

```
Identifier 'AS' preceding ' Date)>Sta' is used incorrectly.
Proper SQL syntax rules have been viloated. The identifier cannot occur where it has been found in the statement. Instad of 'AS', SQL syntax rules allow only: ) ,. If you are using *SEQUEL object authority checking, you cannot use runtime variables in place of the allowed values.
```

ViewPoint Syntax can be strange compared to regular SQL. Very glad we will be rid of it as a standard tool in our shop before long.......

**EDIT2 (SOLUTION):**

As set forth by ***JamesA*** the trick was to use the [DATE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzscadate.htm) function: `DATE(TIMESTAMP)`.

Comment: Have you tried `CAST(table1.TIMESTAMP as /*StartDate Type*/) > StartDate`?

Comment: as my understanding goes.. timestamp is of datetime type and startdate is being string type. So better to convert startdate to datetime type by using cast(startdate as datetime).
So the condition will be 
`timestamp > cast(startdate as datetime)`

Comment: I think some of the error you are seeing are due to the fact your column is named timestamp; which is a reserved word.  You really should have it quoted in your statement.  Otherwise, the system may be confusing it with the TIMESTAMP() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [DATE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzscadate.htm) function to convert the timestamp to just a date portion:

```
SELECT         memno.1 EDTCDE(L), name.2, 'SYS1' NAME(SYS), "&&startdate" NAME(StartDate), CURRENT DATE NAME(CurDate)
FROM           library1/table1, library1/table2
JOIN               SSAN.1=SSAN.2
WHERE          DATE(TIMESTAMP)>StartDate AND RSCODE='STP'
UNION 
SELECT         memno.1 EDTCDE(L), name.2, 'SYS2' NAME(SYS), "&&startdate" NAME(StartDate), CURRENT DATE NAME(CurDate)
FROM           library2/table1, library2/table1
JOIN               SSAN.1=SSAN.2
WHERE          DATE(TIMESTAMP)>StartDate AND RSCODE='STP'
ORDER BY   sys ASC, memno ASC
```

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic I believe Charles answer is more efficient and therefore the better solution.

Answer (score 3):

I am not a SEQUEL expert...

But I suspect there's a way to tell it you want to prompt for an actual date..

Then your query could use the TIMESTAMP_ISO(StartDate) to convert the date to a timestamp.

Note it's better to convert the date to a timestamp than the timestamp to a date since converting the values in the table column will result in indexes not being able to be used.